# How to add back button to WebView?

Tags: java, android

How do I make the back button go back to previous page/link history instead of closing the app?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
  if(WebView.canGoBack()){
   WebView.goBack();
            return true;
  }
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dsaif);
    runDialog(5);
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.loadUrl("http://android.dsaif.tk/store/");
    engine.setWebViewClient( new HelloWebViewClient() );
} 

  private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url ) {                 

         return false;
      }
  }
```

Sorry I'm very new to Android Development and know nothing about Java. Please provide full code :)

Comment: You can use a layout which contains both WebView and some additional controls (back/forward/refresh/whatever) and then in the callbacks of these buttons act upon WebView accordingly

Comment: what is happening with above code?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kostas you create a button in your xml and then in the callback you call `webview.goBack();`

xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back  />
```

activity:

```
Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        engine.goBack();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

This will make the phones back button to go back in history, if there is a history.

```
public class someNameHere extends Activity{
   private WebView engine;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(...){
       ...
       engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
       ...
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(...){
      if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && engine.canGoBack()){
         engine.goBack();
         return true;
      }
      ...
   }
```

Comment: I just want the back button on the phone to work, no buttons on screen

Comment: Then you should call the webview you are using in your `onKeyDown`. You are calling `WebView.goBack();` but it should be `engine.goBack(); ` So you need to declare your webview in your class and not in your `onCreate` method